# How to work with asp.net Image Control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp.net web form that save image as Base64String in MS SQL DB.
But when one opens the same form in two tabs and try to update the image.
The image in tab one will be saved in tab two.

Here is the asp.net Control

```
<asp:Image ID="Image0" runat="server" />   

<asp:FileUpload ID="FUPhoto0" runat="server"  />
```

The code that converts to base 64

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(FUPhoto0.PostedFile.FileName);
        if ((extension == ".png") || (extension == ".PNG"))
        {

            string strFn = FUPhoto0.FileName;
            FileInfo fiImage = new FileInfo(strFn);
            int m_lImageFileLength = FUPhoto0.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            Byte[] m_barrImg = new byte[FUPhoto0.PostedFile.ContentLength];
            System.IO.Stream myStream;
            myStream = FUPhoto0.FileContent;
            myStream.Read(m_barrImg, 0, FUPhoto0.PostedFile.ContentLength);
            string dbImage0 = Convert.ToBase64String(m_barrImg);

            myStream.Close();
        }
```

Decoding base64 string to Image

```
dbImage0 = (string base64string)
String PhotoImg0 = "data:image/png;base64," + dbImage0;
Image1.ImageUrl = PhotoImg0;
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Do you mean the tab control in asp.net ?

Comment: asp:image takes a URL (even the property name is URL), not a file string. You need to save the image first, and then provide the URL. (which also makes sense from a performance viewpoint).